# Android studio does not show 'Lenovo K6' phone in run window

Tags: android-studio, adb

I have "Lenovo K6" phone. I already made a project, when I press run button, android studio does not show my device on that window, what will be the solution?

Comment: Enable USB debugging, possibly install drivers?

Comment: Go to your cell phohe setting and check "debug mode" is open.

Comment: Please don't abuse the tags. This problem is related to Android Studio IDE, and it has nothing to do with `Java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your settings, go to about section and look for build number and tap it repeatedly till you see a toast saying developer mode enabled.

Then, search for the developer option in settings. inside there, you'll find an option saying something like "enable USB debugging" turn that on.

Then, connect your phone through USB while android studio is running. the screen might show a prompt asking for "allow debugging?" or something similar.

now try again.

If you still don't get it, search for how to enable USB debugging on android.

Answer (score 0):

allow `USB debugging` in your mobile, to allow the USB debugging you need to click on Build number 5 to 7 times on your mobile phone settings then go to developer option then enable the debugging.